# Java: How to find all object with the smallest price in the array and print it using toString method in Check class?

Tags: java, arrays

```
checkArray[i] = new Check(checkNumber, payee, amount); // Filled Check object
```

Let say I have:

```
checkArray[i] = new Check(777, Employee1, 8);
checkArray[i] = new Check(88, Employee2, 8);
checkArray[i] = new Check(99, Employee3, 90);
```

So the smallest amounts are `Employee1` and `Employee2` with `8` in the check object array.

How can I print all those Check with same smallest amounts but has different name and check number using toString method in Check class?

Comment: If you use java 1.8 you can do it with streams

Comment: Post the code you wrote to try this and explain specifically which exact part of that code is not working correctly. Don't just say "Here is my assignment. How do I do it?"

Answer (score 1):

Loop through them. Save the smallest value to the variable and comare it afterwards. In case you find the another instance with the same value, save it, else in case you find the new minimum, empty the `List` and store ones with the new minimum value.

I assume you have the getter `getAmount()` returning the `amount`.

```
List<Check> list = new ArrayList<>();
int min = checkArray[0].getAmount();

for (int i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkArray[i].getAmount() < min) {
        min = checkArray[i].getAmount();
        list.clear();
        list.add(checkArray[i]);
    } else if (checkArray[i].getAmount() == min) {
        list.add(checkArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And print them out:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: This won't work, you cannot add anything to Collections.emptyList(), you need to replace it with new ArrayList<>()

Comment: Oh, right.. would you correct me please how to do that?

Comment: it was list = new ArrayList<>(); but simple clear is even better